# Eclipse->File->Import->Android is gone?

Tags: android, eclipse

I don't see "Android" like the image below:

**Some tutorial video screenshot**

[image]

**My eclipse screen shot**
[image]

I'm trying to import

```
android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/google-play-services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

Anyone has any idea on how to do  **Exisiting Android Code Into Workspace** ?

Comment: Use Android studio

Comment: your eclipse is not configured with Android SDK. You need to download sdk and configure it manually. I will recommend you to start development with android studio. Eclipse is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With out adding android sdk and adt plugin to your eclipse, you cant able to view android Folder

Answer (score 2):

Android Plugins are missing in your eclipse IDE. You need to download them in order to develop Android Application.

Now adays Android Application developer uses Android's own IDE i.e. Android Studio. I suggest you to move to Android Studio. You can download it from [Android Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html).